# Why Is JanusGraph Throwing So Many TemporaryLockingException?

Tags: locking, cassandra-3.0, docker-container, janusgraph, java-17

### Problem

How do I release (old) [JanusGraph](https://docs.janusgraph.org/interactions/transactions/) `KeyColumn` locks?

```json
2023-05-11 12:52:47,609 [INFO] [o.j.d.u.BackendOperation.main] ::    Temporary exception during backend operation [CacheMutation]. Attempting backoff retry.
org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.TemporaryLockingException: Lock on KeyColumn [k=0x0xD8000000003FDD80, c=0x0x24] already held by 0x6330613835363363363738302D726D742D6C61702D77696E323031 (we are 0x633061383536336331353636342D726D742D6C61702D77696E323031)
```

I think my issue is all the old expired [`KeyColumn`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.janusgraph/janusgraph-core/latest/org/janusgraph/diskstorage/locking/consistentkey/ConsistentKeyLocker.html) claims.
But I don't know how to tell JanusGraph (or [Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/2.2/cassandra/dml/dmlTransactionsDiffer.html)?) to let the old stuff go,
Or to tell JanusGraph to force claiming the lock or resetting all the locks' statuses.

### Logs

```json
... 

2023-05-11 12:52:47,265 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    g.V().count().next():  70015
2023-05-11 12:52:47,270 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-11 12:52:47,570 [WARN] [o.j.d.l.c.ConsistentKeyLocker.main] ::   Discarded expired claim on KeyColumn [k=0x0xD8000000003FDD80, c=0x0x24] with timestamp 2023-05-09T20:08:57.399330Z
2023-05-11 12:52:47,570 [WARN] [o.j.d.l.c.ConsistentKeyLocker.main] ::   Discarded expired claim on KeyColumn [k=0x0xD8000000003FDD80, c=0x0x24] with timestamp 2023-05-09T20:14:26.991766Z
2023-05-11 12:52:47,570 [WARN] [o.j.d.l.c.ConsistentKeyLocker.main] ::   Discarded expired claim on KeyColumn [k=0x0xD8000000003FDD80, c=0x0x24] with timestamp 2023-05-09T20:20:58.468474Z
2023-05-11 12:52:47,571 [WARN] [o.j.d.l.c.ConsistentKeyLocker.main] ::   Discarded expired claim on KeyColumn [k=0x0xD8000000003FDD80, c=0x0x24] with timestamp 2023-05-09T20:27:09.703971Z
2023-05-11 12:52:47,571 [WARN] [o.j.d.l.c.ConsistentKeyLocker.main] ::   Discarded expired claim on KeyColumn [k=0x0xD8000000003FDD80, c=0x0x24] with timestamp 2023-05-10T14:27:16.668731Z
2023-05-11 12:52:47,572 [WARN] [o.j.d.l.c.ConsistentKeyLocker.main] ::   Discarded expired claim on KeyColumn [k=0x0xD8000000003FDD80, c=0x0x24] with timestamp 2023-05-10T18:30:08.902961Z
2023-05-11 12:52:47,573 [INFO] [o.j.d.u.BackendOperation.main] ::    Temporary exception during backend operation [CacheMutation]. Attempting backoff retry.
org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.TemporaryLockingException: Lock on KeyColumn [k=0x0xD8000000003FDD80, c=0x0x24] already held by 0x6330613835363363363738302D726D742D6C61702D77696E323031 (we are 0x633061383536336331353636342D726D742D6C61702D77696E323031)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ConsistentKeyLocker.checkSeniority(ConsistentKeyLocker.java:514) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ConsistentKeyLocker.checkSingleLock(ConsistentKeyLocker.java:481) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ConsistentKeyLocker.checkSingleLock(ConsistentKeyLocker.java:131) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.AbstractLocker.checkLocks(AbstractLocker.java:348) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ExpectedValueCheckingTransaction.checkAllLocks(ExpectedValueCheckingTransaction.java:178) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ExpectedValueCheckingTransaction.prepareForMutations(ExpectedValueCheckingTransaction.java:157) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ExpectedValueCheckingStoreManager.mutateMany(ExpectedValueCheckingStoreManager.java:77) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction$1.call(CacheTransaction.java:99) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction$1.call(CacheTransaction.java:96) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.executeDirect(BackendOperation.java:66) [janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:52) [janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction.persist(CacheTransaction.java:96) [janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction.flushInternal(CacheTransaction.java:153) [janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction.commit(CacheTransaction.java:210) [janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.commitStorage(BackendTransaction.java:147) [janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.commit(StandardJanusGraph.java:917) [janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx.commit(StandardJanusGraphTx.java:1558) [janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphBlueprintsGraph$GraphTransaction.doCommit(JanusGraphBlueprintsGraph.java:322) [janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.AbstractTransaction.commit(AbstractTransaction.java:104) [gremlin-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphBlueprintsGraph$GraphTransaction.commit(JanusGraphBlueprintsGraph.java:300) [janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094.jar:?]
    at Test9.commitAndOpenJanusgraph(Test9.java:23) [test-classes/:?]
    at Test9.main(Test9.java:17) [test-classes/:?]
2023-05-11 12:52:47,607 [WARN] [o.j.d.l.c.ConsistentKeyLocker.main] ::   Discarded expired claim on KeyColumn [k=0x0xD8000000003FDD80, c=0x0x24] with timestamp 2023-05-09T20:08:57.399330Z
2023-05-11 12:52:47,607 [WARN] [o.j.d.l.c.ConsistentKeyLocker.main] ::   Discarded expired claim on KeyColumn [k=0x0xD8000000003FDD80, c=0x0x24] with timestamp 2023-05-09T20:14:26.991766Z
2023-05-11 12:52:47,608 [WARN] [o.j.d.l.c.ConsistentKeyLocker.main] ::   Discarded expired claim on KeyColumn [k=0x0xD8000000003FDD80, c=0x0x24] with timestamp 2023-05-09T20:20:58.468474Z
2023-05-11 12:52:47,608 [WARN] [o.j.d.l.c.ConsistentKeyLocker.main] ::   Discarded expired claim on KeyColumn [k=0x0xD8000000003FDD80, c=0x0x24] with timestamp 2023-05-09T20:27:09.703971Z
2023-05-11 12:52:47,608 [WARN] [o.j.d.l.c.ConsistentKeyLocker.main] ::   Discarded expired claim on KeyColumn [k=0x0xD8000000003FDD80, c=0x0x24] with timestamp 2023-05-10T14:27:16.668731Z
2023-05-11 12:52:47,608 [WARN] [o.j.d.l.c.ConsistentKeyLocker.main] ::   Discarded expired claim on KeyColumn [k=0x0xD8000000003FDD80, c=0x0x24] with timestamp 2023-05-10T18:30:08.902961Z
2023-05-11 12:52:47,609 [INFO] [o.j.d.u.BackendOperation.main] ::    Temporary exception during backend operation [CacheMutation]. Attempting backoff retry. ...

...
```

### Code

```java
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraph;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphVertex;

public class Test9 {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JanusGraph janusGraph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "cql").set("storage.hostname", "localhost:9042").open();
        GraphTraversalSource g = janusGraph.traversal();
        janusGraph.tx().rollback();
        commitAndOpenJanusgraph(janusGraph);
        logger.info("g.V().count().next():\t" + g.V().count().next());
        g.V().limit(1).drop().iterate();
        commitAndOpenJanusgraph(janusGraph);
        logger.info("g.V().count().next():\t" + g.V().count().next());
        janusGraph.close();
    }

    private static void commitAndOpenJanusgraph(JanusGraph janusGraph) {
        janusGraph.tx().commit();
        janusGraph.tx().open();
    }
}
```

[JanusGraph v1.x.x backend-server](https://docs.janusgraph.org/storage-backend/cassandra/) is a [Cassandra v3.x.x [Docker container]](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra).
This execution is running with: Java-17, Maven-3, and [CQL (Cassandra Query Language)](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/).
This is both about [JanusGraph's locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76219831/why-is-janusgraph-finding-expired-keycolumn-claims) and [Gremlin dropping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76229209/why-does-limit-of-1-not-record-drop-1-vertex).

Comment: Which version of Janusgraph core do you use?

Comment: @Zonko currently [1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.janusgraph/janusgraph-cql/1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094)